# Android updating text line by line in TextView

Tags: android, textview, updating

I am having a TextView to which I am outputting lines of text in a loop. But when I set the text even by appending to existing text it doesnt show till the loop has ended. Is there a way I can update a text view with text line by line

Thanks
-Chandu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the loop to the ui thread or post a runnable with that code. Your code is locked in the loop and the textview cannot be invalidated